# Working with Access database from a 64-bit ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, 64-bit, jet

I have an application uploading Access MDB (its file format) that I need to pull data from.  I HAVE NO CONTROL OVER THIS FILE TYPE OR FORMAT. My problem is that my web application is a 64-bit application and CANNOT BE CHANGED.  JET doesn't work with 64-bit systems.  Every answer I've found is to set my configuration to x86 (32-bit) and I cannot do this with my web application.  I've also tried ACE with the same result.

I need a 64-bit way to read data from an Access data base file, or spin off a 32-bit thread to get to my data, or something.

I am so frustrated.  Access is a misnomer.  They should call it MS MyDataIsTrappedInHell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a separate 32 bit assembly for your data access, which you can then reference in your web application

Comment: I imagine this would work.  The solution I came to was to download the 64-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d&displaylang=en

Comment: It is not possible to access a 32 bit assembly from a 64bit web app... I tried and it doesnt't work... it just compiles, but doesn't run.